# Javascript: onclick function to get elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, object

I'm trying to get the elements of the clicked source, but I don't know why it isn't working.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/msbodetti/HdvGD/)

HTML:

```
<span class="populate" onclick="populate();" href="?id=1">Hello</span>
```

CSS:

```
.populate {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

JS:

```
function populate(event) {
    var event = event || window.event;
    var src = event.srcElement;
    var href = src.getAttribute('href');
    alert(href);
}
```

The error I see in console is that the function populate is not defined.

Any help or suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: var src = event.target || event.srcElement; [Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GKDev/HdvGD/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code works fine in fiddle.  The reason you didn't get it because you wrapped in onload() instead do it in `No wrap in Head` (fiddle at left top)

[your **fiddle1**](http://jsfiddle.net/HdvGD/5/)

Incase you want in onload() assign like variable

```
populate = function (event) {
    var event = event || window.event;
    var src = event.srcElement;
    var href = src.getAttribute('href');
    alert(href);
}
```

Check is [**fiddle2**](http://jsfiddle.net/HdvGD/8/)

Check this [**[answer to find the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/336868/1671639)**]

**Update:**

Sorry for pointing depreciated one(I'hv removed it).  Event object "event" is not passed from the parameter.  Actually here is a simple one 
 passing the event from `onclick` like

```
 onclick="populate(event);"
```

then simple pass it and access like below

```
 function populate(event) {
    var src = event.target || event.srcElement;
    var href = src.getAttribute('href');
    alert(href);
}
```

[**Final Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/HdvGD/15/)

Comment: Thank you, the third fiddle works great. Please can you explain why, would love to know!

Comment: @msbodetti sorry the previous which I mentioned is depreciated. Some browsers still need the `event` object to be passed as parameter.  But I didn't expect FF is not handling this.  Hope you understand.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the order of the javascript and the span tag.

put the javascript function before the tag

JS

```
    function populate(event) {
        var event = event || window.event;
        var src = event.srcElement;
        var href = src.getAttribute('href');
        alert(href);
    }
```

html

```
<span class="populate" onclick="populate();" href="?id=1">Hello</span>
```

We need to define functions before calling them. Fiddle here
http://jsfiddle.net/HdvGD/7/

Answer (score 0):

Anchor tags contain `href` attribute

```
 <a class="populate" id="link" onclick="populate(this.id);" href="......">Hello
</a>



   function populate(id)
   {
       var someimage = document.getElementById(id);
       var mysrc = someimage .src;

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery to get it work as simple

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

     <script type="text/javascript">            

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#populate").click(function(event) {
                alert("As you can see, the link no longer took you to jquery.com");
                var href = $('#populate').attr('href');
                alert(href);
                event.preventDefault();
            });
        });



        </script>
</head>

<body>

<span class="populate" id="populate" onclick="populate();" href="?id=1" >Hello</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But...the question doesn't call for jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Your fiddle works fine, on the left-hand side, second drop-down, change to `No Wrap - In <head>`, now your content is there and script is loaded. Try it again: http://jsfiddle.net/HdvGD/4/